# check null field in linq new object

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(reader);

reader.Close();
connection.Close();

var data2 = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {
     Datetime = x.Field<DateTime>("Datetime"),
     Tagname = x.Field<String>("Tagname"),
     Value = x.Field<Double>("Value")
});
```

When `Value` field is `null`, it throw an exception in casting process. How I can prevent this exception?

Comment: It depends what do you want to happen if Value is null ? Should it stay null or it should be 0, -1 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`null` is a invalid value for `double`

make it nullable (if type of `Value` is nullable or can be changed into it)

```
Value = x.Field<double?>("Value");
```

or define a default value to use in case of `null` (e.g. if `null` then 0)

```
Value = x.Field<double?>("Value") ?? 0;
```

Comment: Thank @fubo, it's Ok

Answer (score 0):

Use x.Field ("Value") in place of x.Field ("Value")

```
 var data2 = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {
        Datetime = x.Field<DateTime>("Datetime"),
        Tagname = x.Field<String>("Tagname"),
        Value =   x.Field <Double?>("Value")

    });
```